# How do i fetch data from UDRn on Mega2560?

Tags: c, arduino, uart, atmega

Noob question: 
I'm trying to learn about UART on an ARDUINO. I wrote some very simple code and for some reason, i can't make the receive() function work. I don't think it fetches the data from the UDR register. I'm using a small OLED display and i want to print the received data to it. No data is being printed to the display, when i run the code. 
I connected the ports TX1 and RX1 with a wire on the board. 
I tried finding youtube videos and have been reading alot. Appearently not enough. 
Any ARDUINO expert who knows what to do?

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "ssd1306.h"
#include "I2C.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void initOLED();
void initUART1();
void receive();
void transmit();

int main(void)
{

    I2C_Init();
    initOLED();                     //initialiaze OLED
    while (1) 
    {
        transmit();
        receive();
    }
}

void initOLED()
{


    I2C_Init();
    InitializeDisplay();
    clear_display();

}

void initUART1(void)
{
    DDRD = 0x08;                     //TXD1 set to output
    UBRR1L = 51;                     //Baudrate 19200
    UBRR1H = 0;                     //upper four bits of baudrate
    UCSR1A = 0x02;                  //Double speed mode
    UCSR1B = 0x18;                  //Enable receive and transmit
    UCSR1C = 0x06;                  //1 stop bit, 8-bit, no parity
}

void transmit()
{
    char b = 'a';
    while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<UDRE1))); //wait for an empty UDR register
    UDR1 = b;                      //load character in register
}
void receive()
{
    int Y = 0;                    //Y coordinate for cursor on the display
    char d;
    while(!(UCSR1A & (1<<RXC1))); //wait for unread data in the receive buffer
    d = UDR1;                     //set UDR register in character d

    sendCharXY(d, 1, Y);          //send character to display
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than that you can't make it work. What does your code do when you run it?

Comment: "I'm using a small OLED display and i want to print the received data to it. No data is being printed to the display, when i run the code." <-- i want to print a character to the screen, but it doesn't. The OLED display is connected correctly, but it seems like it's stuck at "receive()" function, because when i try printing a string to the screen, reight after the receive function, it doesn't print. It prints the string right before the function, so i'm not sure if any data is written to the UDR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you never call `initUART1()`.